# Lemmatization with apache lucene

Tags: java, lucene, nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I'm developing a text analysis project using apache lucene. I need to lemmatize some text (transform the words to their canonical forms). I've already written the code that makes stemming. Using it, I am able to convert the following sentence

> The stem is the part of the word that never changes even when morphologically inflected; a lemma is the base form of the word. For example, from "produced", the lemma is "produce", but the stem is "produc-". This is because there are words such as production

into

> stem part word never chang even when morpholog inflect lemma base form word exampl from produc lemma produc stem produc becaus word product

However, I need to get the base forms of the words: *example* instead of *exampl*, *produce* instead of *produc*, and so on.

I am using lucene because it has analyzers for many languages (I need at least English and Russian). I know about [Stanford NLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) library, but it has no Russian language support.

So is there any way to do lemmatization for several languages like I do stemming using lucene?

The simplified version of my code responsible for stemming:

```
//Using apache tika to identify the language
LanguageIdentifier identifier = new LanguageIdentifier(text);
//getting analyzer according to the language (eg, EnglishAnalyzer for 'en')
Analyzer analyzer = getAnalyzer(identifier.getLanguage());
TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("field", text);
stream.reset();
while (stream.incrementToken()) {
    String stem = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString();
    // doing something with the stem
    System.out.print(stem+ " ");
}
stream.end();
stream.close();
```

**UPDATE:** I found the [library](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/russianmorphology) that does almost what I need (for English and Russian languages) and uses apache lucene (although in its own way), it's definitely worth exploring.

Comment: Did you find a way to lemmatise using Apache Lucene in the end?

Comment: Hi @Jamie! Thanks for drawing attention to this question. Unfortunately I didn't find anything except that library I mentioned in my update. It works well, but supports only English and Russian languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone still needs it, I decided to return to this question and illustrate how to use the [russianmorphology](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/russianmorphology) library I found earlier to do lemmatization for English and Russian languages.

First of all, you will need these [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene.morphology/) (besides the `lucene-core`):

```
<!-- if you need Russain -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene.morphology</groupId>
    <artifactId>russian</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- if you need English-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene.morphology</groupId>
    <artifactId>english</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene.morphology</groupId>
    <artifactId>morph</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, make sure you import the right analyzer:

```
import org.apache.lucene.morphology.english.EnglishAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.morphology.russian.RussianAnalyzer;
```

These analyzers, unlike standard lucene analyzers, use `MorphologyFilter` which converts each word into a set of its normal forms.

So if you use the following code

```
String text = "The stem is the part of the word that never changes even when morphologically inflected; a lemma is the base form of the word. For example, from \"produced\", the lemma is \"produce\", but the stem is \"produc-\". This is because there are words such as production";
Analyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer();
TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("field", text);
stream.reset();
while (stream.incrementToken()) {
    String lemma = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString();
    System.out.print(lemma + " ");
}
stream.end();
stream.close();
```

it will print

> the stem be the part of the word that never change even when
> morphologically inflected inflect a lemma be the base form of the word
> for example from produced produce the lemma be produce but the stem be
> produc this be because there are be word such as production

And for the Russian text

```
String text = "Продолжаю цикл постов об астрологии и науке. Астрология не имеет научного обоснования, но является частью истории науки, частью культуры и общественного сознания. Поэтому астрологический взгляд на науку весьма интересен.";
```

the `RussianAnalyzer` will print the following:

> продолжать цикл пост об астрология и наука астрология не иметь научный
> обоснование но являться часть частью история наука часть частью
> культура и общественный сознание поэтому астрологический взгляд на
> наука весьма интересный

Yo may notice that some words have more that one base form, e.g. `inflected` is converted to `[inflected, inflect]`. If you don't like this behaviour, you would have to change the implementation of the `org.apache.lucene.morphology.analyzer.MorhpologyFilter` (if you are interested in how exactly to do it, let me know and I'll elaborate on this).

Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, StanfordNLP is good for english. But if you need support several language I can recommend you **Freeling**, check its [Freeling_online_demo](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/demo/demo.php), please select language and output (**morphological analysis for lemmatization**). I dont speak russian but I think it works for this text:

> Продолжаю цикл постов об астрологии и науке. Астрология не имеет научного обоснования, но является частью истории науки, частью культуры и общественного сознания. Поэтому астрологический взгляд на науку весьма интересен.

For machine readability you can use the xml output (below your results) and for automatization you can integrate Freeling with python/java but usually I prefer just call it via command line.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I'll definitely try to use this tool in my project. The only drawback is that it's a C++ library and thus it will not be possible to fully integrate it into a Java project

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. In relation to java, I think you can deal the problem using this [Freeling_APIS](https://github.com/TALP-UPC/FreeLing/tree/master/APIs) although it's not a full integration as you said, there are java APIS for linux/windows provided by the Freeling's creator.

Comment: Does Freeling have a lemmatizer?

Comment: Yes it has. You can see the lemmas if you performs POS tagger.